# SQL query is returning null values after join where there should be numeric values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, null, numeric

I am inserting some data from an existing table into a new table. There is a specific column called `DescNitro` which is either returned as 0 or Null in the new table. I've checked specific cases and the Null values are replacing numeric values on the old table. Any idea why this is happening? Code below:

```
DECLARE @DataAtual date = '2021-11-01'; 
DECLARE @UltMes date = DATEADD(MONTH, -1, @DataAtual);
DECLARE @PenUltMes date = DATEADD(MONTH, -2, @DataAtual);
DECLARE @AnoUltMes integer = YEAR(@UltMes);
DECLARE @MesUltMes integer = MONTH(@UltMes);
DECLARE @AnoPenUltMes integer = YEAR(@PenUltMes);
DECLARE @MesPenUltMes integer = MONTH(@PenUltMes);

SELECT
    m.datAno
    ,m.datMes
    ,m.Segmento
    ,m.nomDiretoria
    ,m.nomFilial
    ,m.Ov
    ,o.[Região] AS Filial_Pri
    ,m.[Cod_Rede] AS Cod_Rede
    ,m.Desc_Rede
    ,m.CodSegTatica AS cod_Canal_SAP
    ,m.Canal_Pricing AS cod_Canal_Pri
    ,m.Des_Canal_Pricing
    ,m.codMaterial
    ,m.Vol_Meta AS Vol_Meta_Ciex
    ,m.Fat_Meta AS Fat_Meta_Ciex
    ,g.[DescNitro]
INTO
    [pri].[tblMetaPrecoteste]
FROM
    [pri].[tblDadMetaCiex] m
LEFT JOIN
    dbo.tblCadMaterial mat ON mat.codMaterial = m.codMaterial
LEFT JOIN
    [pri].[tblDadOvFilial] o ON o.[Organização] = m.Ov
LEFT JOIN 
    [pri].[tblDadArvore] a ON a.Material = m.codMaterial
                           AND a.[Filial] = o.[Região]
                           AND a.[Canal de Vendas] = m.[Des_Canal_Pricing]
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT
         t.[codMaterial], 
         t.[codOrganizacaoVenda], 
         t.[codSegTatica], 
         t.[codRede], 
         SUM(t.[DescNitro]) AS DescNitro
     FROM
         [MktIntelligence].[dbo].[tbl_F_PM_join_real_fifo_meta_com_gp] t
     WHERE
         (t.datmes = @MesUltMes AND t.datAno = @AnoUltMes) 
         OR (t.datmes =  @MesPenUltMes AND t.datAno =  @AnoPenUltMes)  
     GROUP BY
         t.[codMaterial], t.[codOrganizacaoVenda], t.[codSegTatica], t.[codRede]) g ON m.[codMaterial] = g.[codMaterial]
               AND m.[Ov] = g.[codOrganizacaoVenda]
               AND m.[codSegTatica] = g.[codSegTatica]
               AND m.[Cod_Rede]  = g.[codRede]
```

Comment: since that's a `left join` therefore if there is no match it will display as `NULL`  otherwise `isnull(columnname,0)` so it will display 0 when it's NULL

Comment: Maybe missing data in tbl_F_PM_join_real_fifo_meta_com_gp for the past 2 months? No match, no g.DescNitro.

Comment: Yes, just identified a problem in CodRede column in one of the tables. It has '1' values where the corresponding columns in the other tables is '01'. Hence, there is no match in these cases, and it's exactly where DescNitro originally has values that are different than zero. Many thanks guys, wouldn't have figured it out by myself!

Answer (score 0):

Since that's a `left join` therefore if there is no match it will display as NULL otherwise use `isnull(columnname,0)` so it will display 0 when it's NULL